# Limit access to a django admin site through apache

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm learning the ropes of the backend and currently trying to use an apache rule to block access to my django app's admin page, a là:

```
    <Directory /admin>

            Order deny,allow

            Deny from all

            Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

    </Directory>
```

I also have my django/mod_wsgi alias set as

```
WSGIScriptAlias /app /home/django/Projects/backend/wsgi.py
```

I'm reading over the docs [here](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/AccessControlMechanisms), and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf), but it's still not 100% clear how I can go about doing this, since in a django project the admin path is not specifically defined (although the static files are). My searches on this are also not turning up much, so either I'm trying to do something no one cares to do, or I'm thinking of doing it wrong (I don't want a password pop up, thank you).

The desired result here is that if you tried to access my admin page from any IP other than what I specify, then your page will just never load or timeout.

Comment: Django admin url is specifically defined: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf

Comment: while it's entirely possible to do this via Apache, probably most often we'd prefer to use Django auth system to control access to admin. you can also use Django middleware to block based on IP address https://github.com/yourabi/django-banish

Comment: if your motivation is to avoid having to log in, by restricting access to a 'trusted' IP please consider that IP address can be faked, which may be why you didn't find other people doing this method http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing

Comment: I'd be happy with any other suggested method but I can't find people trying to limit access to their django admin sites for whatever reason very easily.

Comment: by default the admin is restricted to users with the `is_staff` flag set (or `is_superuser`) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff

Comment: From your earlier suggestion though, how would anyone ever find which IP I'm attempting to restrict access to in the first place?

Comment: maybe they wouldn't... but this is a bad pattern, commonly known as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

Answer (score 10):

Location directive is for URL paths, not the Directory directive.

```
<Location /admin>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Location>
```